# php site_url and base_url not working on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

In codeigniter from view I tried to load a controller function as image src. Like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url('/g1/g2/g3')."?mydata1=".urlencode(serialize($data1)); ?>" />
```

It is working perfectly on my local pc. But on my live server it is not working. I could not figure out whats the problem? Here to mention that the live server is working on https: and in codeigniter

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html', 'string');
```

is on

Comment: hmm.. did you updated the `base_url` in `config.php` file after you uploaded to the live server?

Comment: in config.php.. $config['base_url']= ''; If I echo base_url its showing the correct base url

Comment: If you omit it then CodeIgniter does the "guessing". See if it works after you include the `base_url` of your application in live server

Comment: no luck..  Y cant I use site_url . is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url('/g1/g2/g3');?>?mydata1=<?php echo urlencode(serialize($data1));?>" />
```

Comment: Dude no luck.. still working on the localhost, but on the live server not working

Comment: what does your `site_url()` print?

Comment: tried using `base_url()`? How you want your actual image path?

Comment: As an image path I have to call to this controller function and pass the data, so that the controller funtion can create graph image..

Comment: are you sure u have all the resources required in you live server also? may be something is missing?

Comment: All other controller and views are working properly on live server.. What do u mean by required resources?

Comment: may be some library required to create your graph image?

Comment: its required phpgraphlib and its already uploaded to the server.. my local pc file and server file all are same.. if its required library other it also should not work in local pc. bbut in local pc its running